Uploading Large files(>10MB) to s3 through API Gateway
I have a lambda function which uploads excel files to S3. Since there is limit of 10MB for API Gateway. How can i Upload larger files? Is there a way other than creating a lambda function which geenrates predesigned url of the file.
Is there a way other than creating a lambda function which geenrates predesigned url of the file.

The actual limit is way lower than 10 MB, since requests are base64 encoded when passed to your Lambda. No, the usual approach is to use S3 presigned URLs.
